# CSS3 linear gradient for top and bottom of element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get a linear gradient for the top and bottom of an element. The tutorials found on Google are all over the place, so I'm hoping someone here can help.

This is the HTML and CSS code:

CSS:

```
.content {background: -webkit-gradient(linear, center bottom, center top, from(#f5f5f5), to(#fff));  }
.separator {
    height:1px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ebebeb;
    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="content">

</div>

<div class="separator"></div>

<div class="content">

</div>

<div class="separator"></div>

<!-- etc... ->
```

I want it to produce this:

[image]

Of course, the CSS and HTML I used displays the gradient at the bottom of content. How would I get it to display using both top and bottom with the most minimal HTML?

I will have the content within `.content` so I want it the gradient to be a background image. I could add a gradient for `.separator` but the gradient would not appear behind the next element.

I understand I can use a background image, but I'd like to avoid that route as I have a responsive design. (Yes, I understand I can use a responsive background image, but I'd like to do this CSS-only, no images.)

Comment: not sure I get exactly what your after. You have content in the .content divs, and you want an entire graident from gray to white in every content div? or do you want a continous one behind all the content areas? Or do you want a white to gray to white gradient?

Comment: I want the gradient behind each content.

I just realized I suppose I can an add even-odd CSS sequence. A gradient from white (top) to whiteSmoke (bottom) for the even element, then a gradient from whiteSmoke(top) to white (bottom) for the odd element.

Comment: ah, so its an alternating gradient for each content area, then I would agree, two different gradients would be required (even though they are the reverse of the other), and then applied to the even or odd elements as required

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/nYDAb/11/

Comment: or no change to html - http://jsfiddle.net/nYDAb/32/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will helpful for you

html

```
<div class="contentTop">

</div>

<div class="separator"></div>

<div class="contentBottom">

</div>
```

css

```
.contentTop{
    height:100px;
    background:#ffffff;
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fff), to(#f1f1f1));
    /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff, #f1f1f1);
    /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fff, endColorstr=#f1f1f1);
    /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#fff, endColorstr=#f1f1f1)";   
}
.contentBottom{
    height:100px;
    background:#f5f5f5;
    /* For WebKit (Safari, Google Chrome etc) */
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#fff));
    /* For Mozilla/Gecko (Firefox etc) */
    background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #fff);
    /* For Internet Explorer 5.5 - 7 */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#f5f5f5, endColorstr=#fff);
    /* For Internet Explorer 8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#f5f5f5, endColorstr=#fff)";   
}
.separator{
    border-top:solid 1px #eaeaea;
    height:1px;
    font-size:0;
    line-height:0;
}
```

here is the [jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/a4vA4/)

Comment: Thanks for the effort. The only problem is that the content would be contained to 100px in height.

Comment: if you add content inside the div you can remove the height...I have added the height just because I don't have any content into it